# Send mail as - with no password & username required for SMTP

Tags: gmail

I am currently trying to set up an account to use the "Send mail as:" feature - unfortunately the service provider of my email account requires no username and no password for their SMTP, which the Gmail interface does not allow me to do. Any suggestion to overcome this obstacle?

Answer (score -2):

You could set up a mail client to route mail though Google Mail servers

For example: You send mail from the address `hello@example.com` and route it through your normal SMTP server. It gets there with the address `hello@example.com`.

Example 2: You send mail from the address `hello@example.com` and route it through the GMail SMTP servers. It gets there with the address `hello@example.com via gmail.com`.

to do this:

set your SMTP server to: `smtp.gmail.com` and the email address to the address you want it to display, then the username and password are those of your GMail account.

Comment: Trying this asap, will provide feedback, thanks!

Comment: I just did, Google stopped allowing foreign mails passing through their SMTP, so this isn't an option anymore. http://googlesystem.blogspot.ch/2014/08/external-addresses-no-longer-use-gmail.html

Comment: @mebu83 awww snap! I used to use that all the time.